# Hosting a php application on a Windows Server system. Any issues / advice?

Tags: php, windows, linux, windows-server-2008

We've built a php application that we need to host on a Windows Server 64 bit platform (due to another software being present that we need to access).

However, our php application has been built on a linux environment.

Is there anything we need to be watchful of when running apache and this php application on a Windows environment?

Answer (score 1):

Mostly any PHP script is cross-platform and normally you don't care about platform, but there are some platform-specific things like absolute paths (C:/www | /var/www/) and shell commands. If you don't use them then it will work. If not, it will not take much time for fixing.

Answer (score 1):

There may be some good reading here on the [official PHP documentation on running PHP on Windows](http://php.net/manual/en/install.windows.php).